# Setting `python-shell-interpreter-args` causes slow python mode enabling

Tags: python, ipython

I have a ipython config which imports lots of packages.

I also have some configs in my python setup like

```
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
        python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --profile=ipy --simple-prompt --pprint")
```

Loading a lot of packages will cause slow ipython shell startup. But this also happens when `python-mode` is being enabled.

Moreover, even after opened a python file, when I use <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd> to start an interactive shell, the slow progress happens again. Here is the illustration

[image]

After removing the `--profile=ipy` part, both the mode enabling and interactive shell starting will have a significant speed up.

[image]

I can understand the slowness of starting an interactive shell process when with `--profile=ipy`, but not the python mode enabling.

My question is what is the appropriate way to avoid this ? As I don't see any shell process when python mode is being enabled. The mode enabling is still very slow. 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for going off topic, but what theme are you using ?

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan It's spacemacs-light-theme, available in ELPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `semantic-mode`.

It will call `python-shell-internal-send-string` which depends on `python-shell-interpreter` and `python-shell-interpreter-args`.

Thus using a non-profile `python-shell-interpreter-args` to start this shell and set the profile one back after `semantic-mode` is enabled solves the problem.